# How to configure custom error page in Plesk 9.3 for non existing folder?

Tags: http-status-code-404, directory, custom-errors

I'm trying to configure Plesk in order to show website visitors a custom error html.

The current hosted site is an ASP.NET site. This site shows its custom errors on error403.aspx and error404.aspx files.

Now to comply with plesk, I've created error_docs with required files like forbidden.html, etc...

When user try to navigate http://mysite.com/a_missing_page.aspx, the visitor is redirected to error404.aspx correctly.

But when user try to navigate to a non existent directory http://mysite.com/a_missing_folder/ the site takes me to IIS 404 regular page.

Plesk has Custom error documents activated on Web hosting settings. ASP.NET Error pages defined in web.config are showing fine. But it seems plesk wont show its custom html error documents.

The bottom line here is about setting up a custom error page to a directory. Is it possible to do this using Plesk or do I have to change it manually on IIS?

Comment: I can't see this option in Plesk. I noticed here it can be done on IIS Manager->MySite-> IIS -> Error pages.

Change the current 404 to "/error404.aspx", and 403 for "/error403.aspx".

Next step at right panel click on "Edit Feature settings"
By default IIS presents the option "Detailed errors". Just changed to "Custom error pages" and now It's possible to navigate http://mysite.com/a_missing_folder/ and users is redirected to the correct error403.aspx page. Can Plesk do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log into the domain admin.
open setup
Towards the bottom of the page check "Allow custom error messages"

Of course you need some custome error message pages.

Go to "File Manager" open the error_docs directory and hack away.

You will see (barely) in the lowere right corner tabs for design and HTML. Just paste your code into the HTML field.